# Where is the Reset_Addr, Undef_Addr etc. defined in ARM7?

Tags: assembly, arm, lpc

I am experimenting with the ARM7TDMI-s in LPC2119 and trying to figure out what is in the startup.s code to understand the vector interrupt system.

I have this curiosity where the labels like Reset_Addr and SWI_Addr are defined because they are not in the same file and neither in the header.

```
; Exception Vectors
;  Mapped to Address 0.
;  Absolute addressing mode must be used.
;  Dummy Handlers are implemented as infinite loops which can be modified.

Vectors         LDR     PC, Reset_Addr         
                LDR     PC, Undef_Addr
                LDR     PC, SWI_Addr
                LDR     PC, PAbt_Addr
                LDR     PC, DAbt_Addr
                NOP                            ; Reserved Vector 
;               LDR     PC, IRQ_Addr
                LDR     PC, [PC, #-0x0FF0]     ; Vector from VicVectAddr
                LDR     PC, FIQ_Addr

Reset_Addr      DCD     Reset_Handler
Undef_Addr      DCD     Undef_Handler
SWI_Addr        DCD     SWI_Handler
PAbt_Addr       DCD     PAbt_Handler
DAbt_Addr       DCD     DAbt_Handler
                DCD     0                      ; Reserved Address 
IRQ_Addr        DCD     IRQ_Handler
FIQ_Addr        DCD     FIQ_Handler

Undef_Handler   B       Undef_Handler
SWI_Handler     B       SWI_Handler
PAbt_Handler    B       PAbt_Handler
DAbt_Handler    B       DAbt_Handler
IRQ_Handler     B       IRQ_Handler
FIQ_Handler     B       FIQ_Handler
```

Appreciate any help.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

- I think you're just confused by `armasm` syntax.
- `Reset_Addr` is a label and is defined simply by placing its name in the first column. i.e. `Reset_Addr` is defined by:

`Reset_Addr      DCD     Reset_Handler`

- The same goes for `Undef_Addr` and `SWI_Addr`.
- For a comparison of the relevant ARM vs. GNU assembler syntax, see [Migrating ARM syntax assembly code to GNU syntax: Labels](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0742c/chr1398243831925.html)